# Change SQL value with "onclick" on table cell?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

If we have a simple table (list) as a result of sql select, is there a simple way how to change binary values with onclick on the single cell?

Table structure is:

```
ID  Name  Bin1  Bin2  Bin3
1   Mila  0     0     1
2   John  0     0     0
3   Pato  1     0     0
```

So I searched for some simple JQUERY or AJAX that changes the value of the clicked cell so the page doesn't need to be refreshed if possible...

The idea is to have a table with names, and three (or more) columns, where the cell has a specific color when the value is 1 (and none if 0), and the columns represent IN-OUT-PAUSE states of listed people in this case.

What I have now is a simple list from the database:

[image: Presence table]

Can somebody point me in the right direction? I'm working with MySQL-PHP-HTML combination.

Comment: Invented __what__? Mysql query? PHP db api? Code editor?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

this should help you get started

**Your Ajax Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".my_element").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "my_backend.php",
            data: {value: "new value"}, //send a new value to the "my_backend.php" script
            beforeSend: function (html) {
                //show a preloader here
            },
            success: function (html) {
                //do something if request is successfully completed
            }
        })
    })
})
```

**Your Backend Php Script**

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['value']; // you need to do additional sql injection protection yourself;

$query = mysqli_query($db,"my mysqli updating query")or trigger_error(mysqli_error());

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can on click you can get the text in the table cell, and use a jquery ajax, to give it to a php script. This script can run a mysql query to change the value to 0/1 depending on which value is transferred by the ajax/post request. Then you could start another query to ask for the new value in the database and output this new value (in the php script).

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').on('click','td',function(){
        var currentValue = $(this).text();
        var dbEntryId = $(this).attr('data-dbEntryId');
        $.ajax({
            url: "script.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { dbEntryId: dbEntryId, currentValue: currentValue },
            success: function(result){
                $(this).text(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

As you see, you can use the php output, to put it in the table-cell as new text.

This is only an example for the js part. In this case you have to complement your table-cell with a data-dbEntryId attribute, so that you know, which entry you have to edit in the db.

Answer (score 0):

A possible thing is using attributes on your table.

```
<table id="table-to-click">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Bin1</th>
            <th>Bin2</th>
            <th>Bin3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-id="1" class="table-tr">
            <td data-prop="id" class="t-id">1</td>
            <td data-prop="name" class="t-id">Mila</td>
            <td data-prop="bin1" class="t-id">0</td>
            <td data-prop="bin2" class="t-id">0</td>
            <td data-prop="bin3" class="t-id">1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        //On click on a td in this table
        $("table.table-to-click > tbody > tr.table-tr td").on('click', function(e) {
            //Get field in database to update
            var fieldName = $(this).attr('data-prop');
            //Get id in database (easier that read first td's value)
            var id = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
            //Call server with datas

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "update-field.php",
                data: {
                    field: fieldName,
                    id:    id
                }
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

The code above display a table, and on click on a table cell send a request to update the given field. See [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Note: data-prop is the name of the field in your database.

The code below is your page update-field.php, it receives the request, and does the update in database

```
if (empty($_POST['field']) || empty($_POST['id'])) {
    exit();
}
$fields = ["name", "bin1", "bin2", "bin3"];

//It is only possible to update field in $fields array,
//This is for security reason (to not update id for example)
if (! in_array($_POST['field'], $fields)) {
    exit();
}
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8', 'yourusername', 'yourpassword');
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE yourTable SET :fieldname = (:fieldname + 1) % 2 WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->execute(array(
    'fieldname' => mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['field']),
    'id' => intval($_POST['id']),
));
```

See [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).